# Selecting all posts created by user that actual user follows

Tags: python, django

I have a view that displays posts created by users that actual logged in user follows. It works, by I think the way I've done it isn't good.

BTW, UserProfile is my default user model.

UserFollower model

```
class UserFollower(models.Model):
    followed = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, related_name="followed")
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name="followers", blank=True)
```

Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

My page view

```
class MyPage(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        posts = []
        for user in self.request.user.followers.all():
            for post in Post.objects.filter(author=user.followed):
                posts.append(post)

        return posts
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's focus on the selecting.

```
class MyPage(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        posts = []
        for user in self.request.user.followers.all():
            for post in Post.objects.filter(author=user.followed):
                posts.append(post)

        return posts
```

This is a bit convoluted: you're performing a lot of queries (depending on how many followers a user has). Ideally you'd like to perform just one query.

Also, `get_queryset` looks like it will return a queryset, instead of a list.

```
class MyPage(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(author__followers__follower__id=self.request.user.id)
```

Should work just as well, and returns an actual queryset. (I'm not sure if I got the exact syntax right, please look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships if it does not work).